# Can I make friends with people who aren't my social media friends?

Tags: farmville-country-escape

I want friends! Friends seem awesome! I have a couple through people I know on Facebook, but not a lot of people I know are playing this game. Can I make friends any other way than connecting my social media accounts and using those people?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides your Facebook friends, you can also be virtual friends with people in a Co-Op.  Co-Ops can be accessed via the sign next to your mailbox once you're level 11.  You have to apply to join a Co-Op, and many have minimum required levels (ie, above level 11) as well.

You can buy things your Co-Op friends have for sale, and you can also visit their farms and use Friendship Fertilizer on their crops.

Co-Op friends don't show up if you push the smiley-face "friends" icon in the lower right of the screen, but you can visit their farms by tapping the sign and then tapping on their name/face and choosing "Visit Farm."

Co-Op friends can also send you "Helping Hands" in the form of extra Farm Hands to work your Farm Scenes, which your Facebook friends cannot.  This feature is accessed via the Co-Op chat.  So, it pays to join up!

Comment: Now, to find one....